# In Cognos, can I suppress re-prompting when a report auto-refreshes?

Tags: html, report, cognos

I am passing a value to a prompt (used in the query filter) via the report URL, and further am forcing the report to auto-refresh via an HTML object.  Problem is, the report re-prompts every time the auto-refresh triggers.  Is there a way to have the report auto-refresh, while suppressing the re-prompting?

Comment: Do you want to Set reports to auto refresh or want to prevent refresh?

Comment: When you say 'Re-Prompt' do you mean that the prompt page displays?

Comment: What do you have in your HTML item? And what version of Cognos are you on?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the parameters for a given report are supplied in the URL string, you can add the following to the end of the URL to run the report automatically `&run.prompt=false`.

Note if you do not supply all parameters, it will throw an error.